# How to use NFC Tools to write a 540 byte file to NFC Ntag 215?

Tags: nfc

It seems Tagmo is a tool to write NFC tags, but when I searched on the Google Play Store, [NFC Tools](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wakdev.wdnfc) came out, not Tagmo (and it has a 4.4 out of 5 rating), so I tried using it to write a `.bin` file that is 540 bytes:

1. Email myself in Gmail the file `abc.bin`, which is 540 bytes, using my computer
2. On my Android phone, use Gmail to read that email and download that file
3. On Android phone's NFC Tools, use "Write" -> Add a record -> File, which asked me to install NFC Tasks the app (to read a file, you need an app?)
4. After I install NFC Tasks, I could choose the file from the "Download" folder

But then NFC Tools reports it is "55 bytes", when the file is 540 bytes. When I tried writing the file to an NFC NTag215, it didn't react or waited 45 seconds and said "Write Error".

Is there anything wrong in the above steps?  How do you write a simple file to an Ntag? Is there a better alternative to NFC Tools?

P.S. It seems the 55 byte as reported by NFC Tools might be the "path name" of the file, which is `file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/099 - Abcde (HHD).bin` But why would I write the path of a file to an NTAG? Usually, wouldn't it be writing the "content" of a file to an NTAG?

P.P.S. And when I tried another file, it now reports "Writing 110 bytes" (instead of "Writing 55 bytes"). So what is this writing 110 bytes of file paths, instead of the 540 byte file content to an NTAG? How come it seems there needs to be a 20 page instruction to do a simple thing?)

Comment: Please edit your question and include links to apps you mention (e.g. to Google PlayStore).

Comment: is it very hard to find? It is play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wakdev.wdnfc

Comment: Yes, because depending on the country you are in the app name may be different (translated app name) or the app may be even not listed at all. A link to PlayStore is fixed and uniquely identifies the app.